# Получать объекты рядом (аналог google places). Как это реализовано примерах?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Мне нужно получать список объектов в радиусе 1 км от точки. Например, все кафе или школы. (Знаю про API Поиска по организациям (Геопоиска), который позволяет искать адреса и организации на карте.)

Как реализовать получение нужных мне групп (кафе, школы..)? Т.е. не занося их координаты вручную?

Как это реализовано в данных примерах? 
[пример-1 (карта в середине)](http://xn-------63dbgcuoe2ctjqn1apv9e0j.xn--p1ai/); [пример-2](https://elita-spb.ru/buildings/mirozdanie/infrastructure)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно делать отдельный запрос в HTTP API Геопоиска на каждую рубрику. Например, запросить сначала "кафе", потом "школы" и т.д.